# Understanding Voltage Divider

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I have two very basic questions:

1. Why `Vout = R2 * I2` instead of `Vout = R1 * I1`?
2. Why the current `I1` is equivalent to `I2`?

[image: diagram]

[Reference](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-dividers/all#extra-credit-proof)

Comment: For #2 to be true (and for the voltage divider equation to work), you have to assume $I_{out}$ is 0. Then the explanation is just KCL at the output node.

Comment: And for #1 to be true you have to choose the negative terminal of the voltage source to be the reference node.

Answer (score 1):

If you use $V_{out}$ as voltage supply for your circuit (not drawn in your picture), some current will flow into the circuit. Since the current $I_1$ splits into $I_2$ and $I_{circuit}$, we get $$I_{tot} = I_1 = I_2 + I_{circuit}$$ That's why $I_1 \ne I_2$, if you draw some voltage for your not drawn circuit.

The voltage drop generated by $R_1$ is given by $$I_1 R_1 = \Delta V = V_{in} - V_{out}$$ Hence you can write $$V_{out} = V_{in} - I_1 R_1$$ which is equal to $I_2 R_2$.

Comment: Your answer is far away from what I've asked!

Comment: Well, if you say so.

Comment: But plus one for your time and try :)

Answer (score 1):

Voltage means the difference in electrical potential between two points. $V_{in}$ is the voltage between the two sides of the battery. The upper side of the battery is labelled to be at potential $V_{in}$, the lower side can be assumed to have potential $0$ - ie it is assumed to be grounded. So the potential labelled $V_{out}$ is measured relative to ground at the bottom of the circuit, below $R_2$.

$V_{out}$ equals the potential difference across $R_2$. Applying Ohm's Law, $V_{out}=I_2 R_2$.

As the circuit is drawn, there is no current leaving the circuit at the point marked $V_{out}$. Current does not disappear, it is the same all the way around a circuit, so $I_1=I_2$.

As Semoi shows, if there is an electrical connection between $V_{out}$ and the bottom of this circuit, in parallel with $R_2$, then some of the current will flow into this branch of the circuit. Then $I_1 \ne I_2$, and $V_{out} \ne \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}V_{in}$.

The voltage divider equation $V_{out} = \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}V_{in}$ only applies when no current leaves (or enters) the current loop. This is approximately true if the branch in parallel with $R_2$ has a large resistance $R_3 \gg R_2$. The formula is exact if the branch is included in the current loop by calculating the equivalent resistance $R_{eq}$ of $R_3$ in parallel with $R_2$ and using this to replace $R_2$. That is, $V_{out}=\frac{R_{eq}}{R_1+R_{eq}}V_{in}$.

Comment: I down-voted because your question does not show any research effort. That does not mean that I think it should not be answered.